# Apache POI parallelism support

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

We have a large amount of data to be exported to Excel. In our JAVA application, we use Apache POI, XSSF.

The process is slow because of single threaded, where the data is converted one tab at a time, and one row at a time inside the tab.

Anyone knows if we can use parallelism in the latest release version 5.x?

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10224

Comment: https://github.com/dhatim/fastexcel supports multithreading